# Magento 2 - Error in overriding constructor of Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, ups

**Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Namespace\Module\Model\Ups\Carrier**

Namespace\Module\Model\Ups\Carrier.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Ups;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Framework\Xml\Security;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\AsyncClientInterface;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\ClientFactory;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result\ProxyDeferredFactory;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use Magento\Ups\Helper\Config;

class Carrier extends \Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier
{   
    protected $_localeFormat;

    protected $configHelper;

    private $asyncHttpClient;

    private $deferredProxyFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Security $xmlSecurity,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Simplexml\ElementFactory $xmlElFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\ResultFactory $trackFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\ErrorFactory $trackErrorFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory $trackStatusFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryData,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        Config $configHelper,
        ClientFactory $httpClientFactory,
        array $data = [],
        ?AsyncClientInterface $asyncHttpClient = null,
        ?ProxyDeferredFactory $proxyDeferredFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $scopeConfig,
            $rateErrorFactory,
            $logger,
            $xmlSecurity,
            $xmlElFactory,
            $rateFactory,
            $rateMethodFactory,
            $trackFactory,
            $trackErrorFactory,
            $trackStatusFactory,
            $regionFactory,
            $countryFactory,
            $currencyFactory,
            $directoryData,
            $stockRegistry,
            $data
        );
        $this->_localeFormat = $localeFormat;
        $this->configHelper = $configHelper;
        $this->asyncHttpClient = $asyncHttpClient ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(AsyncClientInterface::class);
        $this->deferredProxyFactory = $proxyDeferredFactory
            ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(ProxyDeferredFactory::class);
    }

    public function setRequest(RateRequest $request)
    {
        $this->_request = $request;

        $rowRequest = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();

        if ($request->getLimitMethod()) {
            $rowRequest->setAction($this->configHelper->getCode('action', 'single'));
            $rowRequest->setProduct($request->getLimitMethod());
        } else {
            $rowRequest->setAction($this->configHelper->getCode('action', 'all'));
            $rowRequest->setProduct('GND' . $this->getConfigData('dest_type'));
        }

        if ($request->getUpsPickup()) {
            $pickup = $request->getUpsPickup();
        } else {
            $pickup = $this->getConfigData('pickup');
        }
        $rowRequest->setPickup($this->configHelper->getCode('pickup', $pickup));

        if ($request->getUpsContainer()) {
            $container = $request->getUpsContainer();
        } else {
            $container = $this->getConfigData('container');
        }
        $rowRequest->setContainer($this->configHelper->getCode('container', $container));

        if ($request->getUpsDestType()) {
            $destType = $request->getUpsDestType();
        } else {
            $destType = $this->getConfigData('dest_type');
        }
        $rowRequest->setDestType($this->configHelper->getCode('dest_type', $destType));

        if ($request->getOrigCountry()) {
            $origCountry = $request->getOrigCountry();
        } else {
            $origCountry = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment::XML_PATH_STORE_COUNTRY_ID,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $request->getStoreId()
            );
        }

        $rowRequest->setOrigCountry($this->_countryFactory->create()->load($origCountry)->getData('iso2_code'));

        if ($request->getOrigRegionCode()) {
            $origRegionCode = $request->getOrigRegionCode();
        } else {
            $origRegionCode = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment::XML_PATH_STORE_REGION_ID,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $request->getStoreId()
            );
        }
        if (is_numeric($origRegionCode)) {
            $origRegionCode = $this->_regionFactory->create()->load($origRegionCode)->getCode();
        }
        $rowRequest->setOrigRegionCode($origRegionCode);

        if ($request->getOrigPostcode()) {
            $rowRequest->setOrigPostal($request->getOrigPostcode());
        } else {
            $rowRequest->setOrigPostal(
                $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment::XML_PATH_STORE_ZIP,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $request->getStoreId()
                )
            );
        }

        if ($request->getOrigCity()) {
            $rowRequest->setOrigCity($request->getOrigCity());
        } else {
            $rowRequest->setOrigCity(
                $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment::XML_PATH_STORE_CITY,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $request->getStoreId()
                )
            );
        }

        if ($request->getDestCountryId()) {
            $destCountry = $request->getDestCountryId();
        } else {
            $destCountry = self::USA_COUNTRY_ID;
        }

        //for UPS, puero rico state for US will assume as puerto rico country
        if ($destCountry == self::USA_COUNTRY_ID && ($request->getDestPostcode() == '00912' ||
            $request->getDestRegionCode() == self::PUERTORICO_COUNTRY_ID)
        ) {
            $destCountry = self::PUERTORICO_COUNTRY_ID;
        }

        // For UPS, Guam state of the USA will be represented by Guam country
        if ($destCountry == self::USA_COUNTRY_ID && $request->getDestRegionCode() == self::GUAM_REGION_CODE) {
            $destCountry = self::GUAM_COUNTRY_ID;
        }

        // For UPS, Las Palmas and Santa Cruz de Tenerife will be represented by Canary Islands country
        if ($destCountry === 'ES' &&
            ($request->getDestRegionCode() === 'Las Palmas'
                || $request->getDestRegionCode() === 'Santa Cruz de Tenerife')
        ) {
            $destCountry = 'IC';
        }

        $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->load($destCountry);
        $rowRequest->setDestCountry($country->getData('iso2_code') ?: $destCountry);

        $rowRequest->setDestRegionCode($request->getDestRegionCode());

        if ($request->getDestPostcode()) {
            $rowRequest->setDestPostal($request->getDestPostcode());
        }

        $weight = $this->getTotalNumOfBoxes($request->getPackageWeight());

        $weight = $this->_getCorrectWeight($weight);

        $rowRequest->setWeight($weight);
        if ($request->getFreeMethodWeight() != $request->getPackageWeight()) {
            $rowRequest->setFreeMethodWeight($request->getFreeMethodWeight());
        }

        $rowRequest->setValue($request->getPackageValue());
        $rowRequest->setValueWithDiscount($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount());

        if ($request->getUpsUnitMeasure()) {
            $unit = $request->getUpsUnitMeasure();
        } else {
            $unit = $this->getConfigData('unit_of_measure');
        }
        $rowRequest->setUnitMeasure($unit);
        $rowRequest->setIsReturn($request->getIsReturn());
        $rowRequest->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax());

        $this->_rawRequest = $rowRequest;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Namespace\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Ups\Carrier" />
</config>
```

**Note: Without constructor function overriding is working but i need to use constructor for custom functionality.**

Help is highly appriciated thank you very much.

Comment: Delete the generated/meta generated/code and do the di:compile again.

Comment: Its in developer mode @SukumarGorai however i have tried after deleting generated folder its same.

Comment: @AmanAlam are you able to find your answers?

Comment: @sumeetbajaj not yet

Answer (score 0):

you used the newest Magento version than the Module. Change the module constructor like this code

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    Security $xmlSecurity,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Simplexml\ElementFactory $xmlElFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\ResultFactory $trackFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\ErrorFactory $trackErrorFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory $trackStatusFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryData,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    Config $configHelper,  
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ClientFactory $httpClientFactory, 
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct(
        $scopeConfig,
        $rateErrorFactory,
        $logger,
        $xmlSecurity,
        $xmlElFactory,
        $rateFactory,
        $rateMethodFactory,
        $trackFactory,
        $trackErrorFactory,
        $trackStatusFactory,
        $regionFactory,
        $countryFactory,
        $currencyFactory,
        $directoryData,
        $stockRegistry,
        $localeFormat,
        $configHelper,
        $httpClientFactory,
        $data
    );
}
```

Or just use auto-generation of IDE to generate the constructor.